# jquery drag and drop elements from a sortable list to another for assign only(not move)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

We have 2 sortable lists (necessary sortable) and I want to be able to drag elements from list 1 over the elements from list 2 without moving any elements from list 2 or list 1 and when I drop the element, it will go back to list 1 (in the same position) and have inside inside it the name of the element from the list 2.

It's like assign tags process. We should be able to assign the same element to multiple elements from other list and to be able to tag elements from list 2 to list 1 also.

I'm not sure if I have to use draggable or droppable scripts from jqueryUI and how. Any ideas how can I do that ?

Thanks!

```js
var sortableOptions = {
  cursor: "move",
  placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
  tolerance: "pointer",
  opacity: 0.8,
  scroll: true,
  scrollSensitivity: 100,
}
$('.list1').sortable(sortableOptions);
$('.list2').sortable(sortableOptions);
```

```css
.list1,
.list2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.list1 .item,
.list2 .item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sortable-placeholder {
  border: 1px dotted #e6e6e6;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list1">
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="item">Item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list2">
  <li class="item">Item 4</li>
  <li class="item">Item 5</li>
  <li class="item">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can use draggable or droppable (I would say droppable seems to meet your needs a bit better), but to keep the origin list intact, you should clone each element, and then append the clone of the origin list to your other list.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first off, if you read jQuery sortable docs, you would know that sortable objects gain the properties of draggable objects.

As such, when you initialize the sortable objects you can set certain properties to handle the sortable events ("start","stop", "recieve", etc)

```
var sortableOptions = {
  cursor: "move",
  placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
  tolerance: "pointer",
  opacity: 0.8,
  scroll: true,
  connectWith: '.list1',
  helper: function(e, li) {
    copyHelper = li.clone().insertAfter(li);
    return li.clone();
  },
  stop: function() {
    copyHelper && copyHelper.remove();
  },
  receive: function(e, ui) {
    let string='<small>'+ui.item[0].innerHTML+"</small>"
    ui.item.prev().html(ui.item.prev().html()+string);
    ui.item.remove()
    copyHelper=null;
  },
  scrollSensitivity: 100,
}
```

**Do note the `connectWith` option** - it makes sure your lists are connected.
I've prepared a fiddle that should reproduce the expected behaviour:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0mtf4ocr/).

**Warning:** The current code does not check for duplicates, so, if you pass item1 from list1 to list2 and back again, you'll have item1 as a duplicate in list1!

**EDIT**

I've changed the fiddle and the code snippet to reflect what you asked, [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/n2c70dk3/1/)

Do note that if you keep changing the items from list to list they will increazingly get bigger. I haven't corrected because it might be the behaviour you expect.

**EDIT2**

Ok, now you've asked for something that got me scratching my head :P

So, my solution to you is:

Change the CSS to:

```
.list1,
.list2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.list1 .item,
.list2 .item {
  float: left; //THIS ONE IS THE IMPORTANT ONE
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sortable-placeholder {
  border: 1px dotted #e6e6e6;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

This will make your lists horizontal (making it very evident that to what element you're appending).

However, if you wish to change to a vertical list, my advice is to stop using scrollable, unless you really need to.
From my research, scrollable will always make "space" for the new element, so either you:

- Alter the jquery library (imo, seems a bad idea),
- You add new event listeners (mouseup/mousedown/mousemove) to **each** list element.
- Or you give up on scrollable and "hard-code" the behaviour you require.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y19bhetg/3/)

Comment: the problem is that I don't want to move any items. just want to be able when I hold and drag an item, the placeholder to highlight elements from list 2(to chose an element from list 2) and when I drop the element, the name of the item from the list 2 to appear near the name of the element from the list 1 (like a tag)

Comment: Ok, see edit, is something like this what you intended?

Comment: we are getting closer :)  the result after drag and drop is't exactly want I want, but there are 2 issues still, when we drag item 1 to the other list, the items from other list tend to "run away". they should not move at all. and a placeholder (border) when we drag hover them would be nice (to know on top of which element we drop the item)

Comment: thank you for your reply. but it's not what I need. those 2 lists have to be vertical and need to have sorting option. and the main problem is that space on list 2 that is added while dragging and the elements that are moving (should not move). that space with placeholder should be on top of the selected element (like a hover border).

Comment: Ok, then I would say you need to do the sorting without sortable. "space on list 2 that is added while dragging and the elements that are moving " this is something jquery sortable does naturally. Either you alter the jquery sortable library (that can mess up some other functions), or just hard code your expected behaviour without using libraries (I think jquery draggable will also make the "space" appear)